# iOS >> ShareKit >> Twitter Settings: How to Get the "bit.ly" Data?

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit, bit.ly

I'm implementing ShareKit with my app and I'm now trying to complete the settings for Twitter. I had created a Twitter application and filled all the fields there and copied all the data to the SHKConfig.h file.
There are 2 fields required in the SHKConfig.h file that I don't understand from where I'm supposed to retrieve the data:

#define SHKBitLyLogin  @""

#define SHKBitLyKey    @""

I understand that I'm supposed to get this "bit.ly" code, but I'm not clear to what does it mean and from where do I get it. I thought I can go on without it, but it causes an error line on the the "share" in Twitter "MISSING_ARG_APIKEY"...

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a user account with bit.ly. Sign in and then visit this URL: http://bitly.com/a/your_api_key. The two pieces of information that it displays should be entered in the ShareKit configuration. This information is from the [bit.ly API Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation).